# Date filter in logstash: bad results(shows one day back)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am loading a CSV file into elastic using logstash

This CSV file contains a column 'deadline' which has dates of the format

```
"deadline": "15-06-2014"
```

I am using the date filter plugin in logstash to get this in date format into elastic

```
  date {
    match => ["deadline","dd-MM-yyyy"]
    target => "deadline_date"
  }
```

But in the output I am receiving the date which has moved one day back

```
"deadline_date": "2014-06-14T18:30:00.000Z"
```

I have one more instance with format like this "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"

```
date {
    match => ["launched","dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"]
    target => "launched_date"
  }
```

Gives result with time changed

```
"launched": "09-09-2013 18:19"

"launched_date": "2013-09-09T12:49:00.000Z"
```

Please help me figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing your [timezone](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-timezone):

```
date {
  match => ["deadline","dd-MM-yyyy"]
  target => "deadline_date"
  timezone => "Etc/GMT"
}
```

Comment: But it still comes with exactly a day back

Comment: I have one more instance with format like this "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" and it is working fine without even me mentioning the timezone

Comment: "launched_date": "2013-09-09T12:49:00.000Z" received from
"launched": "09-09-2013 18:19"

Comment: The time alone has changed

Comment: Well it is actually normal since the date you're storing in `deadline_date` is shown in the GMT timezone.

Comment: So the solution to will be to set the timezone to Etc/GMT?